# C++ Big for-loop stopping randomly long before it should

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am working on an assignment where I am supposed to try out a class I made in four different ways.
This shall be done 100 times in every way, and every single of those 100 iterations contains another for-loop wich runs 5000 iterations.

My problem is that. whilst running, the program randomly stops. It just stops.
No exception. No breakpoint. No crash. No nothing.
It just stops computing.

I've written down a couple of the places it stops
Simplifyed code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    //Some stuff
    for(int j = 0; j < 5000; j++)
    {
        //Some other stuff
        cout << i << "\t" << j << endl;
    }
}
```

Som of the places it has stopped computing at are:

```
3    3564
1    2273
1    4999
2    4999
0    3430
7    4566
1    4916
0    4999
```

So the only pattern I see is that it quite often stops at 4999 of the "j-loop" and very early in the "i-loop".

I am really confused about this since I'm sure that what I'm doing in the loops should not be a problem.

Please help!

[Complete code Link](http://pastebin.com/D99C19wS)

Comment: can you make a [mcve] that replicates the behavior?

Comment: It doesn't get any clearer without me pasting my self-made Class and files.

Comment: That is why I asked for that.  The for loops you have should not stop.  More than likely it is code that you have not shown that is the issue.  keep cutting and trimming unneeded code out of you project until you get the minimal amount of code that produces the same problem and post it here.  Then we might be able to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Added a link to the description, hope that'll help.

Comment: No it doesn't.  We are not a debugging service.  You need to make a [mcve] that reproduces the problem and include the code in the question.

Answer (score 6):

In the first line:

```
for(int i; i < 100; i++)
```

the variable `i` is not initialized. So it contains an arbitrary value that gets incremented every iteration and eventually it stops. Try initializing it: `for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)`.

Comment: That was sadly just a typo I happened to make whilst making this post.
It's initialized as you wrote it in the code and everything compiles nicely.

Comment: @HannesKnutsson Then, please see comment from NathanOliver above and make a minimal, complete and verifiable example, since it works perfectly for me using the code *as is*: http://ideone.com/Ul4fql.

Comment: Added a link to the description, hope that'll help.

Comment: I won't go through your whole code; most likely, something is broken in your disjoint-set implementation. I advice you to get the return code from your program (something like `./my_program; echo $?`) and check if it's not zero. If it's not, good luck with your favourite debugger.